# Opening multiple images in a directory using Image Viewer (Eye of GNOME)

Tags: python, image, file, ubuntu, directory

I've 9025 files (from `img_00000.png` to `img_009024.png`) within a folder and I don't know how to write a python code that allows me to open one Image Viewer's window starting from the first file and that let me click to scroll through all the other images. How could I do this? Thank you!

```py
import glob
flist = glob.glob('out/*.png')
flist = sorted(flist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal you can run the *Eye of GNOME* (*EoG*) using the command `eog`. This command can accept another argument as a directory path which you want to open it in EoG. So you can open a directory using `eog /path/to/directory`. For more options you can run `eog --help`.

Finally you can run this command using `os` in Python.

```py
import os
os.system("eog %s" % "/path/to/directory")
```

Also another alternative is using `subprocess` like below.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["eog", "/path/to/directory"])
```